# How do I ensure my site loads when the user uses the root domain name prefixed with HTTPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku

I'm trying to set up SSL on my site that runs on Rails on Heroku. If I type any of following into the address bar of my browser, it loads:

```
www.example.com
example.com
https://www.example.com
```

But when I enter `https://example.com` (the root domain prefixed with `https`) Safari displays "This connection is not private". Why?

I have added `www.example.com` and `example.com` to my Heroku app.

```
heroku domains:add www.example.com
heroku domains:add www.example.com
```

I have configured the domain's CNAME and ALIAS to point to the DNS targets provided by Heroku.

Alias: `@`    `aaaaaa.herokudns.com.`
CNAME: `www`  `bbbbbb.herokudns.com.`

I have used `heroku certs:auto:enable` to configure Heroku to manage my site's SSL certification.

I have configured rails to force ssl in production:

```
  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true
```

What do I need to do to ensure that the site loads correctly when the user enters the root domain prefixed with `https` into the URL bar?

Comment: _Safari displays "This connection is not private". Why?_ There's a button right next to "This connection is not private" that will explain exactly why it says that.

Comment: you need a SSL certificate?

Comment: Can you check you to ensure that your SSL certificate includes both www.domain.com and domain.com ?

Comment: Turned out to be a transient issue. It's working now. I don't know exactly why.